# uninstall pyzmq

Tags: uninstall, 18.04, pip

I am trying to install jupyter notebook on Ubuntu 18.04 using pip3. However, I run into this error:

> " Cannot uninstall 'pyzmq'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall."

I tried the command below but still no success.

> pip3 uninstall pyzmq

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

What I did to solve a similar problem is that I updated the `pyzmq` first while ignoring previous installations, using the command below:

`pip3 install --ignore-installed pyzmq`

Then, I installed the `jupyter` notebook with the following command:

`pip3 install jupyter`

Answer (score 1):

This probably has to do with the pip version you are using.

You can use pip 9 instead:

```
sudo -H pip3 install pip==9.0.3
```

And than uninstall/install what you need:

```
sudo -H pip3 uninstall pyzmq
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to run this (python 2.7):

```
sudo apt-get remove python-zmq
```